# Calculate bounding boxes of YOLO in ONNX

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

I starting to use the ONNX ecosystem to convert the YOLO model from this [repo](https://github.com/ciber-lab/pictor-ppe). I have succesfully converted and excecuted the model in the ONNX runtime, the idea is to remove the Tensor Flow dependency for the inference, but the conversion is only for the model, I found that the bounding boxes are been calculated using tensor flow function, is it possible to make all this operations in numpy or somehow include this calculation in ONNX?

This is the function I'm refering to:

```
def detection(
    prediction,
    anchor_boxes,
    num_classes,
    image_shape,
    input_shape,
    max_boxes=20,
    score_threshold=0.3,
    iou_threshold=0.45,
    classes_can_overlap=True,
):
    """
    INPUT:
    OUTPUT:
    """

    all_boxes = []

    """@ Each output layer"""
    for output, anchors in zip(prediction, anchor_boxes):

        """Preprocessing"""
        """-------------"""
        # shapes
        batch_size = output.shape[0]
        grid_h, grid_w = output.shape[1:3]

        # reshape to [batch_size, grid_height, grid_width, num_anchors, box_params]
        output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, grid_h, grid_w, len(anchors), num_classes + 5])

        # create a tensor for the anchor boxes
        anchors_tensor = tf.constant(anchors, dtype=output.dtype)

        """Scaling factors"""
        """---------------"""
        image_shape_tensor = tf.cast(image_shape, output.dtype)  # actual image's shape
        grids_shape_tensor = tf.cast(
            output.shape[1:3], output.dtype
        )  # grid_height, grid_width @ output layer
        input_shape_tensor = tf.cast(
            input_shape, output.dtype
        )  # yolo input image's shape

        # reshape
        image_shape_tensor = tf.reshape(image_shape_tensor, [-1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
        grids_shape_tensor = tf.reshape(grids_shape_tensor, [-1, 1, 1, 1, 2])
        input_shape_tensor = tf.reshape(input_shape_tensor, [-1, 1, 1, 1, 2])

        ### Scaling factors
        sized_shape_tensor = tf.round(
            image_shape_tensor
            * tf.reshape(
                tf.reduce_min(input_shape_tensor / image_shape_tensor, axis=-1),
                [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            )
        )
        # to scale the boxes from grid's unit to actual image's pixel unit
        box_scaling = (
            input_shape_tensor
            * image_shape_tensor
            / sized_shape_tensor
            / grids_shape_tensor
        )
        # to offset the boxes
        box_offsets = (
            tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(image_shape_tensor, axis=-1), axis=-1)
            - image_shape_tensor
        ) / 2.0

        """Box geometric properties"""
        """------------------------"""
        grid_h, grid_w = output.shape[1:3]  # grid_height, grid_width @ output layer

        grid_i = tf.reshape(np.arange(grid_h), [-1, 1, 1, 1])
        grid_i = tf.tile(grid_i, [1, grid_w, 1, 1])

        grid_j = tf.reshape(np.arange(grid_w), [1, -1, 1, 1])
        grid_j = tf.tile(grid_j, [grid_h, 1, 1, 1])

        grid_ji = tf.concat([grid_j, grid_i], axis=-1)
        grid_ji = tf.cast(grid_ji, output.dtype)

        # Box centers
        box_xy = output[..., 0:2]
        box_xy = tf.sigmoid(box_xy) + grid_ji

        # Box sizes
        box_wh = output[..., 2:4]
        box_wh = tf.exp(box_wh) * anchors_tensor

        # scale to actual pixel unit
        box_xy = box_xy * box_scaling - box_offsets[..., ::-1]
        box_wh = box_wh * box_scaling

        # calculate top-left corner (x1, y1) and bottom-right corner (x2, y2) of the boxex
        box_x1_y1 = box_xy - box_wh / 2
        box_x2_y2 = box_xy + box_wh / 2

        # top-left corner cannot be negative
        box_x1_y1 = tf.maximum(0, box_x1_y1)
        # bottom-right corner cannot be more than actual image size
        box_x2_y2 = tf.minimum(box_x2_y2, image_shape_tensor[..., ::-1])

        """Box labels and confidences"""
        """--------------------------"""
        # class probabilities = objectness score * conditional class probabilities
        if classes_can_overlap:
            # use sigmoid for the conditional class probabilities
            classs_probs = tf.sigmoid(output[..., 4:5]) * tf.sigmoid(output[..., 5:])
        else:
            # use softmax for the conditional class probabilities
            classs_probs = tf.sigmoid(output[..., 4:5]) * tf.nn.softmax(output[..., 5:])

        box_cl = tf.argmax(classs_probs, axis=-1)  # final classes
        box_sc = tf.reduce_max(classs_probs, axis=-1)  # confidence scores

        """Organize"""
        """--------"""
        # take care of dtype and dimensions
        box_cl = tf.cast(box_cl, output.dtype)
        box_cl = tf.expand_dims(box_cl, axis=-1)
        box_sc = tf.expand_dims(box_sc, axis=-1)

        # store all information as: [ left(x1), top(y1), right(x2), bottom(y2),  confidence, label ]
        boxes = tf.reshape(
            tf.concat([box_x1_y1, box_x2_y2, box_sc, box_cl], axis=-1),
            [batch_size, -1, 6],
        )

        all_boxes.append(boxes)

    # Merge across all output layers
    all_boxes = tf.concat(all_boxes, axis=1)

    # To store all the final results of all images in the batch
    all_final_boxes = []

    """For each image in the batch"""
    for _boxes_ in all_boxes:

        if classes_can_overlap:
            """Perform NMS for each class individually"""

            # to stote the final results of this image
            final_boxes = []

            for class_id in range(num_classes):

                # Get the boxes and scores for this class
                class_boxes = _boxes_[_boxes_[..., -1] == class_id]

                """Non-max-suppression"""
                selected_idc = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
                    class_boxes[..., :4],  # boxes' (y1,x1,y2,x2)
                    class_boxes[..., -2],  # boxes' scores
                    max_output_size=max_boxes,
                    iou_threshold=iou_threshold,
                    score_threshold=score_threshold,
                )

                # boxes selected by nms
                class_boxes = tf.gather(class_boxes, selected_idc)
                final_boxes.append(class_boxes)

            # concatenate boxes for each class in the image
            final_boxes = tf.concat(final_boxes, axis=0)

        else:
            """Perform NMS for all classes"""

            # nms indices
            selected_idc = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
                _boxes_[..., :4],  # boxes' (y1,x1,y2,x2)
                _boxes_[..., -2],  # boxes' scores
                max_output_size=max_boxes,
                iou_threshold=iou_threshold,
                score_threshold=score_threshold,
            )

            # boxes selected by nms
            final_boxes = tf.gather(_boxes_, selected_idc)

        # append final boxes for each image in the batch
        all_final_boxes.append(final_boxes)

    return all_final_boxes
```